# How to modify key in hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I am doing an assignment about a flight booking app. I am encountering the problem about modifying the keys of a `Hashmap` of stored users (including clients and admins).

The keys are a list of strings of personal information like emails, passwords, addresses and ect. What should I do to change some of the information?

The format of personal information is like this: Number, DepartureDateTime, ArrivalDateTime, Airline, Origin, Destination and Price.

Comment: this sounds like a horrible design. Are you using Object Orientation at all ?

Comment: Why this is horrible? Could you explain. Me and my group has a crc model and my part has to has methods that edit the user information.

Comment: Ok I looked at some posts on Stackflow and found out that it might not be good to change the keys and remain the values unchanged. But does that mean my thoughts are never going to work in any ways?

Comment: you say something like "keys are a list of strings", a key should be one single object like one string, a number, not an arbitrary combination of strings for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Object obj = map.remove("oldKey");
map.put("newKey", obj);
```

Once you enter a key you cannot change it. The only way is to replace it.

Comment: What you write is not necessarily correct. If you have keys that are mutable objects then essentially your hashCode could change and hence your key changes. It is therefore recommended to use immutable objects as keys within a hash map

Comment: They way you declare your strings will determine if they are mutable or immutable